# Mirror Windows Server 2008 files to file server

Tags: file, backup, windows-server-2008, mirroring, backup-strategies

I use **Blue Iris** video monitoring software on **Windows Server 2008 R2**. It saves video clips (in its proprietary BVR format) to a local hard drive. Some clips can be several minutes in length.

I want to mirror these clips to a folder on a Linux file server in as close to real time as possible.

At the moment I'm using **Belvedere** to automatically copy any new files from the Windows server to the file server. While this works at a basic level, in practice many of the files being copied to the file server are truncated.

For example, a 3 minute clip on the Windows Server may be only 10 seconds long when it is copied to the file server. I'm guessing that this is because the clip file is still being written to when Belvedere chooses to copy it to the server. 
Belvedere doesn't seem to have any configurable options to correct this.

Can anyone recommend a better way of mirroring my video clips to the file server in real time which takes into account this problem, and which will re-copy files which have been modified since they were first created on the file server?

Answer (score 0):

So I just discovered a tool called Dsychronise, which seems to do exactly what I want. The UI looks a bit primitive, but so far it seems to be doing a correct real-time replication of my files. Fingers crossed....